# Debug Gatsby site on Netlify

Tags: react-hooks, gatsby, netlify

My portfolio is made on Gatsby and deployed to Netlify. It works fine locally but there are bugs on the live site on Netlify. How can I debug this? I cannot use console.log and there are no console errors. How can I debug this?

The issues are to do with a component that shows based on whether a hook is true and the image doesn't render through childImageSharp

Answer (score 1):

If it's being hosted on Netlify, all it is doing is running `gastby build` and then serving the site up from the `public` folder. You should be able to run `gatsby build && gatsby serve` locally to mimic the issue you're seeing on your deployed site. If you can't reproduce it, try cleaning out your `.cache` and `public` folders with `gatsby clean`.